# owl:DatatypeProperty vs. rdfs:subPropertyOf of owl:topDataProperty

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

I am declaring a property as

```
propertyA rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty .
```

I can add more details to `propertyA` as

```
propertyA rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topDataProperty .
```

What additional benefits do I get in the second case? Does it mean that I should always define object or data type properties as subproperties?

Comment: Syntactically, you have one more triple with the second case, but semantically both are the same as any data property is a subproperty of `owl:topDataProperty` - this was just added in OWL 2 and is similar to what `owl:Thing` is for classes.

Comment: it means that the first way to define the property should be sufficient as the second case does not add any useful information that could be leveraged later, in semantic sense.

Comment: Roughly said, yes. The first is sufficient to be OWL 2 compliant and declare the IRI as a data property. As a side note, and because you tagged the question with `sparql`, querying for `?p rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topDataProperty ` would only work with the second case as long as the triple store doesn't support some kind of OWL reasoning. But I don't think that this matters here.

Comment: @AKSW I think this comment would be enough for an answer